# Why am I getting less souls than other players on dark souls?

Tags: dark-souls

I was watching a walk-through of the game and noticed that the player I was watching was somehow getting more souls for each kill. Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: You're going to need to give us more information than that.  Are you in the same area?  Same level?

Comment: My level is the same, in the same area(where there's a dragon on a bridge) where you are supposed to get around 500 souls when the dragon kill all the undead on the bridge, I'm only getting 300 souls.

Comment: Are you sure the dragon is killing the same number of undead?  If it's missing some, that could account for the difference.

Comment: Yeah, im sure its killing all of them, and it counts too for the souls gained for each kill. For example, he gets a kill for 100 souls, if i do the same, im getting only 60 or so.

Comment: Perhaps he is playing NG+?

Comment: There is a ring in the game that can increase the number of souls you get from kills. I do not remember the name though.

Comment: The ring wouldn't raise from 300 to 500 - it only gives a 20% boost. I'd guess the player in the walkthrough is playing New Game+ or later. That is, he's completed the game already and is playing through a second (or third, etc.) time. The number of souls you get increases in NG+.

Comment: It has to be the patch because I've been at the same part with the same stats as others and they got 10k souls for killing the gargoyles when I got 1500 souls. Bogus tbh

Answer (score 5):

I can think of three possibilities:

1. You are not playing on the same patch version as them. As time has gone on, the amount of souls dropped has changed. (mostly increased if I am remembering correctly)
2. They are playing on NG+ or on a higher player through than you. Each time you beat the game, the enemies in the next play through drop more souls.
3. They are wearing the covetous silver serpent ring or symbol of avarice. Each of these items increases the number of souls absorbed.

Update:

I did some hunting based on your comments, and think it is most likely the first option (you are playing on an unpatched version).

http://darksouls.wikidot.com/game-patches

listed under the 1.05 patch:

> Overall increase in souls gained (~2-2.5 times more)

Comment: personally I have experienced this same issue in this same spot. Playing @ my house with a patched version, this area should give you 550 souls. At my friends house unpatched and in offline mode, we were only getting 300.

Comment: Another option is the idea of overkill. When you do greater than 150% of the target's max HP in one attack, a mechanic called 'overkill' takes affect in which the player is awarded a 20% bonus in souls. http://darksouls.wikidot.com/overkill

Comment: While unlikely, if you have the egg sack infection, it steals 50% of your acquired souls...

Answer (score 0):

To gain more souls find the items noted in the previous question and equip them (bare in mind that the symbol of avarice decreases your health slowly) and update your game through the internetthat should give you the most souls you can possibly get bar completing the game and going through to NG+